# Android writing to a text file

Tags: android, bufferedwriter

I have a text file within my raw folder of my app that I intend to use as a simple way to save settings and then read them back when needed.  I can read from this file with using the BufferedReader and what comes with it, but I've tried a few different ways to be able to write to this file and none seem to work.

It seems to me that the problem is I never actually get the file, and I assume this is simply because I don't exactly know how I am supposed to give it the correct directory and file name.  I've tried all I could come up with, and I tend to get errors like "No such file or directory exists" or "Read-only file system".

This seems to be a very simple problem relating to me just giving the wrong information, so if anybody could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Thank you,
Raphy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For saving settings you should use `SharedPreferences` rather than coming up with a custom solution.

- [SharedPreferences documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)
- [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: I figured it would be rather easy since I was already reading from text files in another part of the program, but I suppose writing to them is a different matter.  Thank you for the direction!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure you can do that with stuff in the "raw" folder.

One approach would be to use the SharedPreference storage in the API. See in the datastorage section of the docs. It's perfect from what you describe neededing.  Another approach would be to put the file on the SDCard and read and write it from there.

Comment: Yes, SharedPreferences seem to fit the bill nicely.  Thank you!